# How to add one caption to the top and one to the bottom of a figure?

Tags: floats, captions

Following the suggestion I found on this website, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

I want to include the figure below having one caption at the top and one at the bottom

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{floatrow}
\caption{My caption at the top}\smallskip
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \floatfoot{\textbf{S}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However both captions go at the bottom of the figure, while I would like to have one at the top and the other at the bottom. How can I get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need `floatrow` here? Have you read the manual, e.g. about `floatsetup`? Using a doubled `\caption` (one without numbering, e.g {\caption*}) and not `floatrow` could be easier...

Comment: @Dario May be this could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239044/put-caption-on-top-of-figure-and-source-at-the-bottom-with-two-footnotes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks it worked perfectly.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Would you like to add an answer or should we close it as "solved in comments"?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I think closing is the better variant ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments.